# Why uploading error occured on chrome, but not firefox?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, vue.js

I've developing uploading part.
I've used dropzone plugin to upload file.
If file is small(<100MB), it works well.
But if file is large(>100MB),
`Aw Sanp. Something went wrong while displaying this web page.` error occured on chrome browser.
If I use firefox, it works well without error.

I know chrome uploading limit is larger than firefox, so should work I think.
But why this error happens?
I've tried in incogniter mode, but same.

Please help me.

```
<div class="a-video-container" v-cloak ref="dropZone" :class="dropzoneClass">
    <div class="video-placeholder" v-show="!upload && video.api_id==''" @click="opeFileSelector()">
    <i class="fa fa-file-video icon"></i>
         Drag n Drop video file here to upload
       <div class="alert alert-warning mtm">
          Upload Video.
       </div>
       <input type="file" class="hidden" ref="fileInput" 
                 @change="uploadFileInput()"/>
    </div>


     <div class="progress-layer" v-show="upload">
             Uploading @{{ progress }}%
          <div class="progress-ring"></div>
               Preview not available
               <br/>
               <button class="btn btn-link" 
                    @click="cancelUpload()">cancel</button>
           </div>

           <div class="progress" v-show="upload">
               <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" 
                         role="progressbar"
                                 aria-valuemin="0"
                                 aria-valuemax="100"
                                 v-bind:style="{width: progress + '%'}">
               </div>
               <div class="title under">
                     Uploading @{{ file.name }} | @{{ 
                                 Math.ceil(file.size/1024/1024) }}Mb
               </div>

               <div class="title top" v-bind:style="{width: progress + '%'}">
                                Uploading @{{ file.name }} | @{{ 
                                  Math.ceil(file.size/1024/1024) }}Mb
               </div>
        </div>
</div>

<script>
...
           uploadFileInput(e) {
                    this.startUpload(event.target.files[0]);
           },
           startUpload(file) {

                    this.upload = true;
                    this.file = file;

                    let CancelToken = axios.CancelToken;
                    this.cancelSource = CancelToken.source();

                    this.getBase64(file).then(data => {

                        let params = {
                            name: this.video.title || 'test',
                            description: this.video.description || 'test',
                            notifications: [],
                            file: {
                                name: file.name,
                                data: data
                            },
                            preview: {
                                start: this.video.preview_start,
                                end: this.video.preview_end
                            }
                        }

                        let config = {
                            cancelToken: this.cancelSource.token,
                            onUploadProgress: progressEvent => {
                                var percentCompleted = Math.round((progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total)
                                this.progress = percentCompleted;
                            }
                        }

                        axios.post(this.endpoint + '/api/media', params, config).then(response => {
                            this.video.api_id = response.data.tmp_filename;
                            this.upload = false;
                            this.progress = 0;
                            console.log(this.video.api_id);
                        });

                    });


                },
...
</script>
```

Comment: It's really hard to debug a code you can't see ...

Comment: that is code error? not chrome config or policy?

Comment: please refer this before asking a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Not necessarily a code error, but it would be easier to test, if we had some code to begin with.

Comment: Gather more diagnostics:  https://superuser.com/questions/607563/how-to-determine-what-is-causing-chrome-to-show-the-aw-snap-dialogue

Comment: I've checked given url(```https://superuser.com/questions/607563/how-to-determine-what-is-causing-chrome-to-show-the-aw-snap-dialogue```) but when error occurred there's not any log.